# Problem in message section in orders of product prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Somebody know in what phisical file in prestashop 1.7.5 (TPL) appear the message sections of product orders? i need modificate the line where show the message (red circle) because don't appear good the message (UTF8 problems)

Attach image

[image]

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

This looks an old PS 1.7 version, the whole admin order page had been migrated to twig/Symfony already so consider upgrading to v1.7.8.5 as maybe they already fixed this issue.

Anyway, that message content is rendered in this template :

**{your_admin_dir}/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/helpers/view/view.tpl**